# Click Once Deployment : Application validation did not succeed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2017, clickonce

I have had a look through the various articles and spent many hours googling for a fix to my specific issue.

My application runs fine when debugging, but when I come to deploy to Click Once I cannot install the eventual created application. I have recently rebuilt my laptop and this error has only started occurring since then.

I have tried to remove and re-add the specific references. I have tried signing the application and various other suggestions from this site and others. None specifically seem to fix my issue.

When I try to install the application I get the error "Application validation did not succeed" and it leads to the below log file:

```
    PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.16299.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.3062.0 built by: NET472REL1
    clr.dll             : 4.7.3190.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
    dfdll.dll           : 4.7.3062.0 built by: NET472REL1
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://URL//Karate%20Admin.application
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
                        X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET
    Deployment Provider url     : http://URL/Karate%20Admin.application
    Application url         : http://URL//Application%20Files/Karate%20Admin_1_0_0_37/Karate%20Admin.exe.manifest
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
                        X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Karate Admin.application, Version=1.0.0.37, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil
    Application Identity        : Karate Admin.exe, Version=1.0.0.37, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://URL//Karate%20Admin.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Strong name signature not valid for this assembly System.Management.Automation.dll.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [14/10/2018 18:38:11] : Activation of http://URL//Karate%20Admin.application has started.
    * [14/10/2018 18:38:11] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [14/10/2018 18:38:11] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [14/10/2018 18:38:11] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [14/10/2018 18:38:13] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [14/10/2018 18:38:13] : Detecting dependent assembly System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A using System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
    * [14/10/2018 18:38:13] : Detecting dependent assembly System.Net.Http.Rtc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A using System.Net.Http.Rtc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
    * [14/10/2018 18:38:13] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [14/10/2018 18:38:23] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SignatureValidation)
        - Strong name signature not valid for this assembly System.Management.Automation.dll.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyStrongNameAssembly(String filePath, AssemblyManifest assemblyManifest)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyComponents()
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

If anyone can give me some suggestions to fix this, I would be forever thankful!

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: The error message *"Strong name signature not valid for this assembly System.Management.Automation.dll"* seems to suggest that something may be corrupt in your .NET Framework installation.

Comment: You have shared your application publish address, strongly recommend to remove it. I did tried to install http://install.rsmcd.co.uk/KarateAdminSystem/Karate%20Admin.application and everything was fine. Have you tried to clear C:\Users\<YOURUSERNAME>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\* folder ?

Comment: Hi Sergey, thanks... I've removed the URL... I missed it in my frustration!

Comment: I'm just trying a clean PC Rebuild as I suspect that its something to do with my Framework being corrupt... Will let you know the outcome.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like Sergey nailed it on the head, it was something corrupt with my .NET Framework. Weirdly I had tried to fix and re-install the framework with no luck.

A full reset of my laptop with a fresh windows build did the trick, maybe there was a conflict somewhere.